# Can not find index of combobox item when using a List as datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, list, combobox

I'm populating a list from a LINQ Query, then I am using the list as the data source for a combo box.

I am then trying to select items within the combo box but it doesn't seem to be able to find the index

```
using (var db = new CruxEntities())
{
    var query = from q in db.Businesses
    where q.BusinessID == BusinessId
    select q;

    var B = query.FirstOrDefault();

    if (B != null)
    {
        // other form controls populated

        var sites = B.TblBusinessSites.ToList();

        this.comboBox.DisplayMember = "SiteName";
        this.comboBox.ValueMember = "BusinessSiteID";
        this.comboBox.DataSource = sites;

        int index = comboBox.FindString(B.IdFromLinq);
    }
}
```

index always has the value of -1 assigned to it but i've stepped through the code and I know that the value exists in the list... it seems to be that the rest of the code is not recognising that the combo box has the values.

What am I missing?

---

Edit

---

I got the index fine... but something I missed out from my initial post is that there are 2 combo boxes bound to the list... I get the indexes for both of them fine when I step through the code but the combo boxes seem linked so I assigning the index to either one seems to assign it to both...

```
index = sites.FindIndex(s => s.BusinessSiteID == B.PrimarySiteDeliveryID);
comboBox_DefaultDeliverySite.SelectedIndex = index;

index = sites.FindIndex(s => s.BusinessSiteID == B.PrimarySiteInvoiceID);
comboBox_DefaultInvoiceSite.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: What's the value of `IdFromLinq`?

Comment: Why not just get the index from the List? they should be the same.

Comment: The value of IdFromLinq is the ID of the FK in the business table (which matches one of the values in List - I did step through the code to verify this)

Comment: What gives you the property `comboBox.Items.Count`? Is this 0 or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find site index because `FindString` method checks item's displayed text (site name in your case), but you are trying to search by ID, which is item's value.

Actually you even don't need to touch combobox here, because items will be added in same order as you have them in `sites` collection. To get index of some site you can just search index of site in `sites` list:

```
int index = sites.FindIndex(s => s.BusinessSiteID == B.IdFromLinq);
```

Comment: ok, using your method I got the index fine... but something I missed out from my initial post is that there are 2 combo boxes bound to the list... I get the indexes for both of them fine when I step through the code but the combo boxes seem linked so I assigning the index to either one seems to assign it to both...


`index = sites.FindIndex(s => s.BusinessSiteID == B.PrimarySiteDeliveryID);
comboBox_DefaultDeliverySite.SelectedIndex = index;

index = sites.FindIndex(s => s.BusinessSiteID == B.PrimarySiteInvoiceID);
comboBox_DefaultInvoiceSite.SelectedIndex = index;`

Comment: @DannySeager are you sure you change `index` variable value between two assignments?

Comment: Positive. I've even created 2 variables - 1 for each combo box.

Both combo boxes select the last value, so if I put the delivery site 2nd then both combo boxes have the PrimarySiteDeliveryID selected but if I move the Invoice site 2nd then both combo boxes have the PrimarySiteInvoiceID selected.

Comment: I've just changed the code to use 2 separate lists and it works ok.. but I don't think it should need separate lists really....

Comment: @DannySeager it's hard to tell what is going wrong in your code. It should work without any problems. In debugger check values of `index` before you assigning it to each of comboboxes.

Comment: That's what I was doing. I've just changed the code to use 1 List and both combo boxes get the same value selected. When I use 2 lists they get different (and correct) values selected.

Comment: @DannySeager you can start another question, which describes your problem and has code to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

The `FindString` method is not a good choice, since you are binding with objects, so stick to object, not string.

You can loop on your item instead :

```
foreach(var item in comboBox.Items)
{
    var businessSite = item as BusinessSite;
    if(businessSite != null && businessSite.BusinessSiteID == B.IdFromLinq)
    {
        // your item here
    }
}
```

Or index based:

```
for(int index = 0; index < comboBox.Items.Count; index++)
{
    var item = comboBox.Items[index];
    var businessSite = item as BusinessSite;
    if(businessSite != null && businessSite.BusinessSiteID == B.IdFromLinq)
    {
        return index;
    }
}
```